# XMLParse( ) throwing Content is not allowed in prolog error

Tags: xml, coldfusion, xml-parsing

I'm currently having trouble with `XMLParse()`, as the title says, it keeps throwing this error

```
An error occured while Parsing an XML document.
Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

My code is pretty basic at the moment, I'm just trying to get it to dump the XML values.

```
<cfset XMLPOST = GetHTTPRequestData().content>
<cfset xmlDOM = XMLParse(XMLPOST)>
<cfdump var="#xmlDOM#">
```

I've tried [Ben Nadels](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1206-Content-Is-Not-Allowed-In-Prolog-ColdFusion-XML-And-The-Byte-Order-Mark-BOM-.htm) method of determining whether it was a BOM or not, and his dump gave me this output

```
[x] - 120
[m] - 109
[l] - 108
[=] - 61
[%] - 37
[3] - 51
```

which seems to me like there isn't a problem with that character.

The XML is being posted to our server so I wonder if it that causing the problem? The XML which is being posted is in this format

```
xml=%3Cjob%3E%0D%0A++++%3Cjobref%3EExample+jobref%3C%2Fjobref%3E%0D%0A++++%3Cjobtitle%3EExample+jobtitle%3C%2Fjobtitle%3E%0D%0A++++%3Cdescription%3EExample+description%3C%2Fdescription%3E%0D%0A%3Cjob%3E%0D%0A++++++++++++
```

I have a feeling that it is this which is causing the errors? When I manually specify this XML on my document as a variable in its original form

```
<job>
    <jobref>Example jobref</jobref>
    <jobtitle>Example jobtitle</jobtitle>
    <description>Example description</description>
<job>
```

and parse that variable, it dumps fine.

I assume that what I will need to do is change the XML Post format to a different format before I try to parse it? I have tried to use `ToString()` but to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try trimming the form.xml variable: `trim(form.xml)`? I had a few cases where leading whitespaces caused this errormessage.

Comment: `<cfset xmlDOM = XMLParse(TRIM(XMLPOST))>` still throws this error.

Comment: `isXML(XMLPOST)` outputs `NO`?

Comment: In your example the last `<job>` should be the closing one: `</job>`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15759/discussion-between-seybsen-and-joshua-m)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the raw content of the request you should use ColdFusion's FORM-Scope which will handle URLdecode etc. for you and splits up the body to seperate variables:

Replace:

```
<cfset XMLPOST = GetHTTPRequestData().content>
<cfset xmlDOM = XMLParse(XMLPOST)>
<cfdump var="#xmlDOM#">
```

With:

```
<cfset XMLPOST = FORM.xml>
<cfdump var="#XMLParse(XMLPOST)#">
```

Maybe you'd also want to check if it's valid XML which is posted with [`isXML()`](https://cfdocs.org/isxml)-function.